# Looping over a column and replacing values if condition is met in r

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm still a beginner to R, and I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite my indexing in my loop.

I have a column `party` that just lists political party affiliations. I have a loop that I wrote to replace any values that are not either `democrat` or `republican` in the column.

```
for(i in 1:length(party3$party)){
  if(party3$party[i] != "democrat" || party3$party[i] != "republican"){
  party3$party[i] <- "I" }}
```

My column `party` looks something like this:

```
party
republican
independent
democrat
libertarian
independent
american independent
republican
democrat
```

And I'm trying to keep `democrat` and `republican` intact:

```
party
republican
I
democrat
I
I
I
republican
democrat
```

Problem is, everything ends up being replaced with "I". How do I fix this loop's indexing?

Comment: `party3$party[!party3$party %in% c("republican","democrat")] <- "I"`

Answer (score 1):

You could assign the values without `for` loop :

```
party3$party[!party3$party %in% c("democrat", "republican")] <- 'I'

#       party
#1 republican
#2          I
#3   democrat
#4          I
#5          I
#6          I
#7          I
#8 republican
#9   democrat
```

---

In your `for` loop you need to use `&&` instead of `||` and it should replace values when both the values are not present.

```
for(i in 1:length(party3$party)) {
  if(party3$party[i] != "democrat" && party3$party[i] != "republican"){
    party3$party[i] <- "I" 
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, but what if I wanted to make it even shorter with an `ifelse` command instead? I have `party3 <- senate_df_rm_na %>%
  select(party) %>%
    mutate(party_coded = ifelse(party3$party == 'democrat' || party3$party =='republican',1,0))` but I keep getting a whole column of 1 in my added column... (senate_df_rm_na is the whole df I am working with, example above is just a snippet of the `party` column in it)

Comment: `||` is for scalar comparisons. Use `|`, `senate_df_rm_na %>%   select(party) %>%     mutate(party_coded = ifelse(party == 'democrat' |party =='republican',1,0)`. Also you can do this without `ifelse`. `senate_df_rm_na %>%  
  select(party) %>% 
  mutate(party_coded = as.numeric(party == 'democrat' | party =='republican'))`